# Label with an Image on the left - preventing the text to come over the picture?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I want to report status of an operation in a WinForm application written in C#.
To make it more user-friendly, I want to show an icon on the left depending on the status.

- Animated GIF during the process
- Ok or Error icon depending on the result.

I wanted to use the native WinForms Label control which works well with animated GIFs and looks as standard as it can get.

My problem however is that text comes is written over the picture.
There does not seem to be any property to set a margin for the text.
I tried the most obvious thing, which is to prefix it with spaces, which works, except when the text wraps to the next line, as shown below.

[image]

I would prefer not spend too much time writing/testing/debugging derived control for this if possible...
I could put a quick and dirty user-control, with a picturebox on the left of a label, but it doesn't feel very clean.

Is there any trick to get around this quickly and elegantly, or can someone point me to a Label derived class supporting this that is relatively lightweight? (I had a look at CodeProject but couldn't find much).

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty usercontrol with an image and a separate label is your best option. Just add a public string property to set the label's text and you're pretty much done.

Answer (score 32):

A simple alternative is to use a `Button` instead of a `Label`, as shown below:

[image]

By using the following properties, you can style the `Button` to look just like a `Label`, whilst also having the option to keep the image and text aligned next to eachother:

```
FlatAppearance ↴
  BorderSize         = 0
  MouseDownBackColor = Control
  MouseOverBackColor = Control
FlatStyle            = Flat
Image                = [Your image]
ImageAlign           = MiddleLeft
Text                 = [Your text]
TextAlign            = MiddleLeft
TextImageRelation    = ImageBeforeText
```

A simple way to achieve the desired effect; no user controls!

Comment: Clever idea although in my case I can still click it and the button looks pressed then. Setting Enabled to false makes it looks different (image greyed out, gif animation stopped).

Comment: @KharlosDominguez That's strange, I managed to get it looking perfectly. I'll have a look at it a little later and report back!

Comment: @KharlosDominguez I don't think you set `FlatAppearance` → `MouseDownBackColor` to `Control` (or your background colour). That's the only thing I can do to replicate what you're saying.

Comment: Hello Danny. Simple but perfect solution. Your answer could be selected as the best one.

Comment: I love this answer. I can easily center an image and its text in the center of the form without adding any code.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different solution that I find less hacky than the "styled button" approach. It also allows you to set the distance (spacing) between the image and the text.

```
class ImageLabel : Label
{
    public ImageLabel()
    {
        ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    }

    private Image _image;
    public new Image Image
    {
        get { return _image; }

        set
        {
            const int spacing = 4;

            if (_image != null)
                Padding = new Padding(Padding.Left - spacing - _image.Width, Padding.Top, Padding.Right, Padding.Bottom);

            if (value != null)
                Padding = new Padding(Padding.Left + spacing + value.Width, Padding.Top, Padding.Right, Padding.Bottom);

            _image = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Image != null)
        {
            Rectangle r = CalcImageRenderBounds(Image, ClientRectangle, ImageAlign);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, r);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e); // Paint text
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for left align, i am trying to use it for middle center align but its not working, any suggestion on what padding values will work for middlecenter?

Answer (score 2):

I think, I've found even simpler solution:

```
Label.Width = Label.Image.Width + 5 + TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, Label.Font).Width
```

Label has to be set like this (it can be set on Designer):

```
Label.AutoSize = False
Label.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
Label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to a `UserControl` would be to use a `TableLayoutPanel` with two columns and one row, placing the image control in one cell and the text control in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question, but maybe someone will look here just like I got here...

You can use the Align on the Image and on the text:

```
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
label.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Comment: Not true. Your solution can still overlap text with image depending on the size of the control. Also it does really address the issue. You are actually trying to make them far from each other

Comment: It works because your label text size and the image size are small enough. if you try to make the label smaller, they will overlap. In some cases, if you do not resize the control, or change the label text, your solution is acceptable. But you are not addressing the question (try making it work with a multi-line text, like shown in the question)

Comment: Kind of same approach is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75881162/356726

Answer (score -12):

```
nameoftextlabel.hidden=1
```

That should work.

Comment: 1) `hidden` is not a valid property; 2) `1` is not a valid boolean; 3) hiding the label wouldn't help anyway